# How to use multiple react-native-modal same time

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-modal library, in my project i want to implement one modal on top of another modal, it is not working on ios but perfectly works on android..

I want to use one modal at a time while other modal is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can have two modals at the same time is by nesting the second modal inside the first modal.For now this is the best solution for the current version of the library.